# Determine wheter the set $B = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | 3x^2 + 2y^2 \lt 6 \}$ is open or closed and calculate its boundary

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I don't know if the process I've done is correct.

First of all, we have the following set:

$$B = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | 3x^2 + 2y^2 \lt 6 \}$$

Then I can say that the boundary is $y = \sqrt{(6-3x^2)/2}$, and as the definition of the set it says $\lt$, any point of the set will belong to its boundary, so the set is open.

Is this correct or am I wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(x, y) \mapsto (\sqrt{3}x, \sqrt{2}y)$ is a homeomorphism and homeomorphism preserves closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary consists of all points $(x,y)$ with $y =\pm  \frac 1  {\sqrt 2} \sqrt {6-3x^{2}}$.  The set is open and not closed.

Comment: The 1/2 is at the wrong place because the factor at $y^2$ is 2.

Comment: But is it open because at the definition it stated $3x^2+2y^2 \lt 6$? I mean, if that were $3x^2+2y^2 \le 6$ would it be closed?

Comment: @galgarabel Yes. in that case the set would be closed but the boundary would be remain the same.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thank you.